# rsync error - Unexpected remote arg: root@1.2.3.4:/*

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I'm trying to migrate centos server to a new box with rsync and I run this command in the destination server:

```
 rsync -auHxv –numeric-ids –exclude=/etc/fstab
 –exclude=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/* –exclude=/proc/*
 –exclude=/tmp/* –exclude=/sys/* –exclude=/dev/* –exclude=/mnt/*
 –exclude=/boot/* –exclude=/root/* root@1.2.3.4:/* /
```

And then I get this error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: root@1.2.3.4:/*
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: A google search revealed http://www.linuxhelp.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=10405

Answer (score 9):

I just got a similar error, and the following things might fix your problem:

- Ensure `--exclude` has *two* hyphens preceding it
- Place quotes around your excluded paths like `--exclude '/boot/*'`

The error is confusing, because it's not actually about the destination parameter, but often the parameters coming before it having incorrect syntax.

Comment: it was the previous parameter for me too

Comment: same here - it didn't like `--progress` where I put it

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tip:  Put the word `echo` in front of the command.  You'll then see how the full expanded command line looks to the program.

In this case you would see the parameters with `*` expanded to contain multiple paths - not what you wanted or thought you had typed in - which at least points you in the right direction to fix the issue.